# ORA-00904: "GRADE_RANK": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

This query runs without `grade_rank > 1` but I want only the results where grade_rank is > 1. I have tried using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as grade_rank` but it didn't work.

```
SELECT
    student_id,
    section_id,
    grade_type_code,
    grade_code_occurrence,
    numeric_grade,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        PARTITION BY student_id, section_id, grade_type_code
        ORDER BY
            numeric_grade ASC
    )  grade_rank
FROM
    grade
WHERE
    (student_id = 102
    AND section_id = 86
    )
```

This is the result of the above query which is not what I quite want. I need the results with grade_rank > 1
[image]

Comment: This [Oracle documentation](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-analytic-functions/oracle-row_number/) suggests using `WITH x AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() ...) SELECT * FROM x WHERE pay_rank > 1`.

Comment: @KenY-N Using a sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. a CTE or `WITH` clause) is, in that case, effectively the same as using nested sub-queries.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Code and explanation is updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option using a subquery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT
        employee_id,
        dept_id,
        pay_type,
        pay_code,
        pay_grade,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY employee_id, dept_id, pay_type
            ORDER BY
                pay_grade ASC
        ) pay_rank
    FROM
        grade
    WHERE
        (employee_id = 99
        AND dept_id = 11)
) t
WHERE pay_rank > 1
```

Comment: It doesn't return any result

Comment: @HamzaMahmood Do you have more than 1 person with the `employee_id` of `99` and the `dept_id` of `11`? If the answer is no, then of course it won't show any rows. Perhaps you should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64922206/edit) your question and tell us what you are attempting to do and include a [MRE] with some sample data and your expected output.

Comment: I've updated the code and added results, I hope it makes more sense now

Comment: I've no idea why but I tried this query again and it has worked. Thanks @MT0

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de0c0cec06a697fafc4b404a789e4011)